# Combine keys of a yaml file on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, yaml

Is there a manner to combine two yaml files (same keys merged together) ...
I remember in the past that this was possible using intelliJ. But this feature is not working actually. I'm using IntelliJ 2019.1 ..

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA didn't have this feature. A request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: Allright, done : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227028?project=IDEA